# WSO2 IdentitiServer 5.10.0 :How to integrate route mobile SMS Provider with Wso2 Identity server MFA

Tags: azure, kubernetes, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have integrated WSO2 Identity Server Multifactor Authentication with our web application,
and tested the SMS Otp Using Nexmo(Vonage) free account.
Now we wanted to integrate route mobile sms provider for sending sms otp, however it will have message validation ( send only configured message format).
So how to configure $ctx.msg to send messages format configured in route mobile.

**we are using below steps to integrate MFA using route mobile:**
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-sms-otp/

Route mobile SMS Url format:

```
https://host/bulksms/bulksms?username=xxx&password=yyy&type=0&dlr=1&destination=$ctx.num&source=xxx&message=Your OTP code is $ctx.msg Kindly use it to verify your contact number on xxxx Application. Code valid for 5 minutes only.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the message template  for the SMS in  `<HOME>/repository/conf/sms/sms-templates-admin-config.xml`. After the change, restart the server.

If you don't want to restart the server, you can follow[1] and change the template in Registry.

FYI, [2] is a good read to setup up SMS OTP in wso2 is

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Managing+SMS+Notification+Templates+Using+the+Registry
[2]https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/self-registration-with-sms-confirmation-in-wso2-identity-server-5-10-0-onwards-fb59e6465631